# javascript inject in uiwebview of iOS 8

Tags: javascript, objective-c, uiwebview, ios8

I am testing my project in iOS 8 preview 2. 
And now I faces two problems about the uiwebview
I use the following code to inject my script

```
NSString *jsCLOSE_WINDOW = @"function CLOSE_WINDOW(){
    document.location ='mySchema://FUNCTION=CLOSE_WINDOW';
}";
[self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsCLOSE_WINDOW];
```

in `"-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView"`
and get the response in

```
 - (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
```

it works fine in iOS 7.1 and earlier. 
But in iOS 8 preview 2

```
1.document.location = 'mySchema://FUNCTION=CLOSE_WINDOW'; 
seems not working anymore? I can't get the response in "shouldStartLoadWithRequest"
2.in iOS 7.1 and earlier every time page redirect to another
 (ex:page1.html -> page2.html -> page3.html) 
"webViewDidFinishLoad" will be triggered in every page. 
But, in iOS 8 preview 2 it only triggered once in first page
```

How do I fix these?, or that is the new limitations in iOS 8?
any ideas? appreciate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After lot of search.
Finally, I got a solution,
just follow the link [link here](https://gist.github.com/irace/3688560).
the problem is the javascript.
rewrite the javascript as the sample style
and it works fine in iOS 8(tested in Beta3) right now.

Answer (score 1):

iOS8 seems cannot get through `:` or either `=` in your case just after the function name. Try doing a replacement from the line

```
document.location ='mySchema://FUNCTION=CLOSE_WINDOW';
```

to use the `?` mark like

```
document.location ='mySchema://FUNCTION?CLOSE_WINDOW';
```

should works.